# How can i delete key from the object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const newdata = {biddate: new Date(), productId: id, bidamount: bid, username: user.displayName, email: user.email};
};
```

i want to delete key from this object.

Comment: Your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/208106/9294837

Comment: Which key? `delete newData.myProperty`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove properties from objects (JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/remove-properties-from-objects-javascript)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 0):

```
    delete newdata.email;
```

You can try this